# Powershell - Get-AdGroupMember exceeding limit

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following query

```
$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter * | Where     {
            ($_.name -like "*") 

} | select ObjectGUID -expandproperty ObjectGUID)


$Table = @()

$Record = [ordered]@{
    "Group _ObjectGUID" = ""
    "Name" = ""
    "SamAccountName" = ""
    "Member_ObjectGUID" = ""
}


Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive -identity $Group  | select name,samaccountname,ObjectGUID

    foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
    {
        $Record."Group _ObjectGUID" = $Group
        $Record."Name" = $Member.name
        $Record."SamAccountName" = $Member.SamAccountName
        $Record."Member_ObjectGUID" = $Member.ObjectGUID
        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
        $Table += $objrecord
    }

}

$Table | export-csv "C:\temp\AD_group_members.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

however i am unable to execute the query as it exceeds the maximum ad return of 5000 it specifically returns the following error message

> Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded At
>   line:22 char:20
>   +     $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive -identity $Group  | select name, ...
>   +                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (70206804-1c23-4e47-8e9e-e8fb7c688826:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember],
>   ADException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The size limit for this request was exceeded,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember

I can't think of a way to trim this down to get around this because the solution of changing the config on all the domain controllers (300ish) is not an option.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this problem just today as well.  What you have to do is get the group with the properties of member:

```
$ADInfo = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Properties Members
```

Now, $ADInfo holds the group and it's members.  To get the list of members:

```
$ADInfo.Members
```

And if you want the members AD record, do the following:

```
$ADInfo.Members | Get-ADComputer
```

Or you can put it all together:

```
(Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Properties Members).Members | Get-ADComputer
```

I'm using the Get-ADComputer but the same works for Get-ADUser.

Comment: if a group has child groups in it, get-adgroupmember tackles that using -recursive, however get-adgroup or get-aduser and get-adcomputer throw an error with -recursive. thought ?